# How to order by a tag's name?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a tag like this `<article mdate="2005-12-08" key="journals/presence/RobinettR92">`

How do I say ordering by the tags "name" the name being article for example (this is not the only name so I can't use an absolute path)?

To select ordering by the `mdate` attribute for example I can use `{for i in $item order by $i/@mdate}` and that works, but nothing I try seems to sort by the tags name.

Comment: Downvote for: "nothing I try" - please show _what_ you tried (especially for rather basic and obvious homework questions), the code you posted is broken and would not execute with the input provided (please test code before posting, and copy/paste it), and the input you provided is especially inadequate for _sorting_ (multiple elements seem rather reasonable in this case).

Answer (score 0):

To order the tag names, use the `local-name(...)` function.

```
for $i in $item
order by local-name($i)
return $i
```